# Fail to use ibpy to send Futures order in InteractiveBrokers

Tags: python-2.7, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I am using ibpy to send orders to TWS in InteractiveBrokers.  I am able to send stock orders, such as SPY, but I am unable to send Futures.  Here is the code I am using, copied online:

```
from ib.opt import Connection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order

def make_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, prim_exch, curr):
    Contract.m_symbol = symbol
    Contract.m_secType = sec_type
    Contract.m_exchange = exch
    Contract.m_primaryExch = prim_exch
    Contract.m_currency = curr
    return Contract

def make_order(action,quantity, price = None):
    if price is not None:
        order = Order()
        order.m_orderType = 'LMT'
        order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
        order.m_action = action
        order.m_lmtPrice = price
    else:
        order = Order()
        order.m_orderType = 'MKT'
        order.m_totalQuantity = quantity
        order.m_action = action
    return order

orderId=300
conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=999)
conn.connect()
cont = make_contract('SPY', 'STK', 'SMART', 'SMART', 'USD')
trade = make_order('BUY', 1, 273)
conn.placeOrder(orderId, cont, trade)
conn.disconnect()
```

The code above works well.  I am able to place a bid in SPY at 273.

However, I want to buy E-mini Futures S&P 500 Dec Contract.  I made the following to define the contract:

```
def make_fut():
    Contract.m_symbol = 'ES'
    Contract.m_secType = 'FUT'
    Contract.m_exchange = 'GLOBEX'
    Contract.m_primaryExch = 'GLOBEX'
    Contract.m_currency = 'USD'
    Contract.m_lastTradeDateOrContractMonth ='201812'
    return Contract

cont = make_fut()
```

It did not go through and it did not get back error messages.  Does any one have some experience in this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code.
https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/blob/master/ib/ext/Contract.py
`m_expiry = ""`
So just use `m_expiry = '201812'`

It doesn't use the new name `lastTradeDateOrContractMonth`.  You tagged this python 2.7 but if you use python 3, you can use the python API from IB which will have some newer features.   https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041 . That does use the new field name (without the m_ styles).

Also `Contract.m_primaryExch = 'GLOBEX'` is unnecessary.  It's for when you specify SMART for exchange and it is ambiguous.  eg. I think for your SPY example you should specify ARCA, but it is also unnecessary since there's only one SPY stock(etf).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for building futures contracts:

```
def create_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, curr, exp = None, mult = None, localsymbol=None):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.m_symbol = symbol
    contract.m_secType = sec_type
    contract.m_exchange = exch
    contract.m_currency = curr
    contract.m_expiry = exp
    contract.m_multiplier = mult
    contract.m_localSymbol = localsymbol
    return contract
```

For futures I can get by with `symbol` and `exp` OR I can set `symbol = None` and set `localsymbol` (e.g. PLJ9 = Platinum April 2019).

I've never needed `prim_exch`.